# Checking the text field for error whether it is blank or not

Tags: grails, gsp

The code below has jquery loaded. so i need to do validation without it.
There are lots of fields in   i cant set constraints to nullable:false and blank:false in domain class and i need to validate it in gsp file. i want to validate these fields which are inside of tbody. the data are populated manually and by upload too. i just need to check whether it is blank or not and throw error msg when these required fields are null or blank

the gsp code is:

```
      <td>
              <g:textField name="Number.1" id="Number_1" class="requiredFields"
                  data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-optional="true"/>
      </td>

      <td>
          <g:textField name="iNumber.1" id="iNumber_1" class="requiredFields"
                    data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-optional="true"/>
       </td>

       <td><g:hiddenField name="iAmountNew.1" id="iAmountNew_1"/>

            <g:textField class="requiredFields" name="iAmount.1" id="iAmount_1"
                   ="formatCurrency(this.id)" data-validation-optional="true"/>
        </td>
```

Comment: inside <tbody> there are lots of textfield. the above are 3 fields which i need to validate for null values without using jquery. is there any way to check whether these fields contain null or blank values??

Comment: Using Javascript on the client? HTML5 attributes on the client? On the server using Grails validation constraints? You still haven't shown in your question the code you have written to try and solve the problem and explained what issues you are having with your code. If you improve your question someone else might help you solve the problem.